# How can I extract submitbuttonnextstatusid value from a rendered HTML from an input tag whose id is "submitbutton"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I extract submitbuttonnextstatusid value from a rendered HTML from an input tag whose id is "submitbutton"?

My Page renders HTML like the following and I need to extract value for submitbuttonnextstatusid.

My rendered HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="ButtonSm" onclick="this.form.submitbuttonid.value='WlFVC1pOfzstOBIZO2UiCggMe0p1HBE3H2Be';this.form.dele.value=0;this.form.submitbuttonnextstatusid.value=25259;this.form.save.value=1;this.form.butaction.value=2;" value="Confirmation Letters" id="submitbutton">
```

In this case I need 25259.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to match the id from the `onclick` attribute:

```
var rgx = /submitbuttonnextstatusid\.value=(\d+);/;
var statusid = $('#submitbutton').attr('onclick').match(rgx)[1];
console.log(statusid);
```

Check [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/T8Q4j/).